# How to write Junit for Exception

Tags: java, junit

My Class contains following handleException method for which I have to write JUnit with full code coverage. As I am new to JUnit can anybody help

```
public void handleException(Exception exception, DCMRequestDTO requestDTO, DCMResponseDTO responseDTO, String callType) {
    logger.error("Exception occured for deviceId:" + requestDTO.getDeviceID() + ",RefNum:"+
            requestDTO.getRefNum() + ",Operation:" + requestDTO.getOperation() + "::" + exception.getMessage());
    exception.printStackTrace();
    String errorMessageKey = "GENERIC_EXCEPTION";
    if (exception instanceof TooManyInflightException) {
        errorMessageKey = "THROTTLE_EXCEPTION";
    } else if (exception.getCause() instanceof SocketTimeoutException ||
            (exception.getCause() != null && exception.getCause().getCause() instanceof SocketTimeoutException)) {
        errorMessageKey = "TIMEOUT_EXCEPTION";
    } else if (exception.getCause().getCause() instanceof ConnectException || exception.getCause().getCause() instanceof ConnectTimeoutException || exception.getCause().getCause() instanceof UnknownHostException || exception.getCause().getCause() instanceof MalformedURLException || exception.getCause().getCause() instanceof SocketException || (exception.getMessage().indexOf("404 Error") != -1)) {
        errorMessageKey = "CONNECTION_EXCEPTION";
    } else if(exception.getMessage().indexOf("500")!=-1){
        errorMessageKey = "INTERNAL_ERROR";
    }
    /*
     * else if (exception instanceof DCMException) { if (exception.getCause().getCause() instanceof SocketTimeoutException) { errorMessageKey = "TIMEOUT_EXCEPTION"; } else if (exception.getCause().getCause() instanceof ConnectException || exception.getCause().getCause() instanceof IOException || exception.getCause().getCause() instanceof SocketException || (exception.getMessage().indexOf("404 Error") != -1)) { errorMessageKey = "CONNECTION_EXCEPTION"; } }
     */
    // logger.error(errorMessageKey + " occured in DCMServiceImpl :: UniqueId = " + requestDTO.getUniqueId() + ", RefNum = " + requestDTO.getRefNum() + ", Operation = " + requestDTO.getOperation() + ", callType = " + callType, exception);
    // added for reset time while exception occured
    responseDTO.setErrorCode(0);
    responseDTO.setErrorString(smartGraphUtils.getProperty(errorMessageKey));
    responseDTO.setStackTrace(exception.toString());
    responseDTO.setHasJson(false);
    requestDTO.setHidResolveGetRetrains("Undetermined");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your source code you need an instance of the surrounding class inside the tests: then you should be able to call the method `handleException`.
Each test should consist (in best case) of only one assert. This makes easy to understand what you are currently checking.
Here is an example:

```
public final class MessageBusTest {
    @Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
    public void registerWithNullThrowsNullPointerException() {
        MessageBus.INSTANCE.register(null);
    }
}
```

The annotation `@Test` helps JUnit to figure out which methods in a class are tests. In my example I call a method with `null` and expect an exception to be thrown, hence the `expected = NullPointerException.class`.

In your case you have to e.g. prepare the proper `Exception` for a test and then check the `requestDTO` for the content, i.e. the error string, with an `assertEquals`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your method has got many flows and you need to write tests for each flow/condition inside your method to ensure all scenarios are handled.

Sample code has been provided below to start with and you can write the complete logic:

```
import org.junit.Test;

    public class HandleExceptionText {

        @Test
        public void testHandleExceptionForTooManyInflightException()  {
            //throw TooManyInflightException exception and then call handleException()
            //Example using Mockito: when(obj.method(parms)).thenThrow(new TooManyInflightException());
            //Assert to check responseDTO values have been set
        }

        @Test
        public void testHandleExceptionForSocketTimeoutException()   {
            //throw SocketTimeoutException exception and then call handleException()
            //Example using Mockito: when(obj.method(parms)).thenThrow(new SocketTimeoutException());
            //Assert to check responseDTO values have been set
        }

        @Test
        public void testHandleExceptionForConnectTimeoutException()   {
            //throw ConnectTimeoutException exception and then call handleException()
            //Example using Mockito: when(obj.method(parms)).thenThrow(new ConnectTimeoutException());
            //Assert to check responseDTO values have been set
        }

        @Test
        public void testHandleExceptionForConnectException()   {
            //throw ConnectException exception and then call handleException()
            //Example using Mockito: when(obj.method(parms)).thenThrow(new ConnectException());
            //Assert to check responseDTO values have been set
        }

        @Test
        public void testHandleExceptionForUnknownHostException()   {
            //throw UnknownHostException exception and then call handleException()
            //Example using Mockito: when(obj.method(parms)).thenThrow(new UnknownHostException());
            //Assert to check responseDTO values have been set
        }

        @Test
        public void testHandleExceptionForMalformedURLException()   {
            //throw MalformedURLException exception and then call handleException()
            //Example using Mockito: when(obj.method(parms)).thenThrow(new MalformedURLException());
            //Assert to check responseDTO values have been set
        }

        @Test
        public void testHandleExceptionForConnectException()  {
            //throw SocketException exception and then call handleException()
            //Example using Mockito: when(obj.method(parms)).thenThrow(new SocketException());
            //Assert to check responseDTO values have been set
        }

    }
```

Also, I suggest going through the below JUnit & Mockito tutorial links:
https://dzone.com/articles/junit-tutorial-beginners
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mockito/mockito_exception_handling.htm

Comment: @Test
 public final void testhandleException() throws Exception {given(smartGraphServiceHelper.generateDocument(Mockito.any(DCMRequestDTO.class))).willThrow(new SocketTimeoutException());
  
  String callType = "";
  
  smartGraphService.handleException(exception, requestDTO, responseDTO, callType);
  assertEquals("0",responseDTO.getErrorCode());
 }   this is what i have tried but gives nullpointer when it goes inside the exception.getCause()